# $routeProvider is not defined - Unable to get through this

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've been trying to get a basic project running with ng-route.

I have two views - View A and View B. They are controlled per

```
flipFlop.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view/a', {
             templateUrl: 'app/viewA.html',
             controller: 'ViewAController'
     })
        .when('/view/b', {
            templateUrl: 'app/viewB.html',
            controller: 'ViewBController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/view/a'
        });
}]);
```

My index.html file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="flipFlop">



<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app/flipFlop.js"></script>
<script src="./app/ViewAController.js"></script>
<script src="./app/ViewBController.js"></script>

<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and each of my view files look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div id = "viewB">View B</div>
</html>
```

The error log looks like

[image]

It looks like a very stupid mistake. Could someone please point it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the `flipFlop` module first..

```js
const flipFlop = angular.module('flipFlop', ['ngRoute']);
flipFlop.config([ ... ])
```

Comment: What I see right now: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flipFlop due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider